# Designing a circuit for wireless interrogation of a temperature SAW sensor

Tags: rf, sensor, wireless, transceiver

I'm currently working on a SAW-based temperature sensor. The gist of how it works is this: when the external temperature changes, the resonance frequency of the SAW resonator shifts. To detect the shift wirelessly and passively, we use a transceiver to send a series of sine waves spanning the entire frequency range of the system. An antenna connected to the resonator receives the signals and provides power to the resonator. When the excitation is switched off, the resonator slowly releases the energy to the antenna, sending it back to the transceiver. There, the received signal is digitized and processed, and the resonance frequency shift is measured.
The overall architecture should look something like this:
[image]

I and the people I'm working with mostly focus on the design of the SAW sensor part, we are not expert in RF electronics. I'm wondering if a transceiver like the one above is commercially available that could be connected to a PC and controlled so as to be able to send and receive the required signals whenever we like. The working frequency is around 370 MHz.

Comment: You might be able to do something with a software-defined radio.

Comment: The impedance that the SAW resonator presents to its electrical terminals is required to be known at all possible frequencies. Distance range between the SAW device and the interrogating antenna needs to be defined.

Comment: This architecture looks very similar to a coherent pulsed radar. Although the waveform you show suggests the use of a stepped FMCW radar - but note that this would most likely use a circulator or separate RX and TX antennas, rather than the TX/RX switch.